# A Java EE7 web application for counting views in a static HTML page

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, servlets

I have [this blog](http://coderodde.github.io/weblog/) lurking around in the web. It's just static HTML, but I was interested to keep track of all the views on that blog. Finally, I end up with the following web application:

(The Java backend resides entirely [here](https://github.com/coderodde/WeblogViewCounter).)

**`com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.CountViewServlet.java`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter;

import com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotAddViewException;
import com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotCreateMainTableException;

import static com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.Utils.objs;
import com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotGetMostRecenetViewTimeException;
import com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotGetNumberOfViewsException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * This servlet is responsible for storing the IP-address and the timestamp of 
 * a view in at <a href="http://coderodde.github.io/weblog/">coderodde's weblog</a>.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Aug 21, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Aug 21, 2021)
 */
@WebServlet(name="CountViewServlet", urlPatterns={"/countView"})
public final class CountViewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Gson GSON = new Gson();
    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            Logger.getLogger(CountViewServlet.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                          HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Allow the weblog page to get the response from this servlet:
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
                                      "coderodde.github.io");

        DataAccessObject dataAccessObject = DataAccessObject.getInstance();
        JSONResponseObject jsonResponseObject = new JSONResponseObject();
        jsonResponseObject.succeeded = false;

        try {
            dataAccessObject.createTablesIfNeeded();
            ZonedDateTime mostRecentViewTime = 
                    dataAccessObject.getMostRecentViewTime();

            if (mostRecentViewTime != null) {
                jsonResponseObject.mostRecentViewTime =
                        mostRecentViewTime.toString();
            }

            dataAccessObject.addView(httpServletRequest); 
            jsonResponseObject.numberOfViews = dataAccessObject.getViewCount();

            // Mark as successful:
            jsonResponseObject.succeeded = true;


        } catch (CannotCreateMainTableException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE, 
                    "Could not create the main table: {0}, caused by: {1}", 
                    objs(ex.getCause().getMessage(), 
                         ex.getCause().getCause()));

        } catch (CannotAddViewException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE, 
                    "Could not add a view: {0}, caused by: {1}", 
                    objs(ex.getCause().getMessage(), 
                         ex.getCause().getCause()));

        } catch (CannotGetMostRecenetViewTimeException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE, 
                    "Could not get the most recent view time: {0}, " + 
                            "caused by: {1}", 
                    objs(ex.getCause().getMessage(), 
                         ex.getCause().getCause()));

        } catch (CannotGetNumberOfViewsException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE, 
                    "Could not get the number of views: {0}, caused by: {1}", 
                    objs(ex.getCause().getMessage(), 
                         ex.getCause().getCause()));
        }

        try (PrintWriter printWriter = httpServletResponse.getWriter()) {
            printWriter.print(GSON.toJson(jsonResponseObject));
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.DataAccessObject.java`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter;

import com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.sql.SQLStatements;
import com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotAddViewException;
import com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotCreateMainTableException;
import com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotGetMostRecenetViewTimeException;
import com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotGetNumberOfViewsException;
import static com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.Utils.objs;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

/**
 * This class implements the data access object for the view counter.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Aug 22, 2021)
 */
public final class DataAccessObject {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
            Logger.getLogger(DataAccessObject.class.getName());

    private static final String EUROPE_HELSINKI_ZONE_ID = "Europe/Helsinki";
    private static final ZoneId ZONE_ID = ZoneId.of(EUROPE_HELSINKI_ZONE_ID);

    private static final String DB_URL_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME = 
            "CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL";

    private static final DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    private static final DataAccessObject INSTANCE = new DataAccessObject();

    public static DataAccessObject getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    /**
     * Makes sure that the main table is created.
     * 
     * @throws CannotCreateMainTableException if cannot create the table.
     */
    public void createTablesIfNeeded() throws CannotCreateMainTableException {

        try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
            connection.createStatement()
                      .executeUpdate(SQLStatements
                                      .ViewTable
                                      .Create
                                      .CREATE_MAIN_TABLE);

        } catch (SQLException cause) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE, 
                    "The SQL layer failed: {0}, caused by: {1}", 
                    objs(cause.getMessage(), cause.getCause()));

            throw new CannotCreateMainTableException(cause);
        } catch (URISyntaxException cause) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE, 
                    "URI failed: {0}, caused by: {1}", 
                    objs(cause.getMessage(), cause.getCause()));

            throw new CannotCreateMainTableException(cause);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new view data to the database.
     * 
     * @param httpServletRequest the request object.
     * @throws com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotAddViewException
     * if adding a view data fails.
     */
    public void addView(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) 
            throws CannotAddViewException {

        String host = httpServletRequest.getRemoteHost();
        int port = httpServletRequest.getRemotePort();
        String remoteAddress = httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");

        if (remoteAddress == null) {
            remoteAddress = httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
        }

        try (Connection connection = getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement =
                     connection.prepareStatement(
                             SQLStatements.ViewTable.Insert.INSERT_VIEW)) {

            statement.setString(1, remoteAddress);
            statement.setString(2, host);
            statement.setInt(3, port);

            ZonedDateTime nowZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZONE_ID);

            Timestamp nowTimestamp = 
                    Timestamp.from(nowZonedDateTime.toInstant());

            statement.setTimestamp(4, nowTimestamp);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            throw new CannotAddViewException(cause);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the total number of views. 
     * @return the total number of views so far.
     * @throws com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.exceptions.CannotGetNumberOfViewsException
     * if cannot get the number of views.
     */
    public int getViewCount() throws CannotGetNumberOfViewsException {
        try (Connection connection = getConnection();
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {

            try (ResultSet resultSet =
                    statement.executeQuery(
                            SQLStatements
                                    .ViewTable
                                    .Select
                                    .GET_NUMBER_OF_VIEWS)) {

                if (!resultSet.next()) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "Could not read the number of views.");
                }

                return resultSet.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new CannotGetNumberOfViewsException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the most recent view time stamp.
     * @return the most recent view time.
     * @throws CannotGetMostRecenetViewTimeException if reading the most recent
     * view time fails.
     */
    public ZonedDateTime getMostRecentViewTime() 
            throws CannotGetMostRecenetViewTimeException {
        try (Connection connection = getConnection();
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {

            try (ResultSet resultSet = 
                    statement.executeQuery(
                            SQLStatements
                                    .ViewTable
                                    .Select
                                    .GET_MOST_RECENT_VIEW_TIME)) {

                if (!resultSet.next()) {
                    return null;
                }

                Timestamp mostRecentViewTimestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(1);

                if (mostRecentViewTimestamp == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                ZonedDateTime mostRecentViewZonedDateTime =
                        ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
                                mostRecentViewTimestamp.toInstant(), 
                                ZONE_ID);

                return mostRecentViewZonedDateTime;
            }

        } catch (SQLException | URISyntaxException ex) {
            throw new CannotGetMostRecenetViewTimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void loadJDBCDriverClass() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE, 
                    "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver class not found: {0}, " + 
                            "caused by: {1}", 
                    objs(ex, ex.getCause()));

            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver not found.", 
                    ex);

        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE, 
                    "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver could not be instantiated: {0}," +
                            " caused by: {1}", 
                    objs(ex, ex.getCause()));

            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver could not be instantiated.", 
                    ex);

        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(
                    Level.SEVERE, 
                    "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver could not be accessed: {0}, " + 
                            "caused by: {1}", 
                    objs(ex, ex.getCause()));

            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver could not be accessed.", 
                    ex);
        }
    }

    static {
        loadJDBCDriverClass();
    }

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, URISyntaxException {
        URI databaseURI = 
                new URI(System.getenv(DB_URL_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME));

        String username = databaseURI.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
        String password = databaseURI.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
        String databaseURL = 
                "jdbc:mysql://" + databaseURI.getHost() + databaseURI.getPath();

        return DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, username, password);
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.JSONResponseObject.java`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter;

/**
 * This POJO class type defines a simple object for reporting to the front-end.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Aug 22, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Aug 22, 2021)
 */
public final class JSONResponseObject {

    public boolean succeeded;
    public int numberOfViews;
    public String mostRecentViewTime;
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.sql.SQLDefinitions.java`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.sql;

/**
 * This class defines the database table schemas.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Aug 22, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Aug 22, 2021)
 */
public final class SQLDefinitions {

    /**
     * This class defines the structure of the main table.
     */
    public static final class ViewTable {

        /**
         * The name of the main table.
         */
        public static final String NAME = "view";

        /**
         * This class defines the ID column.
         */
        public static final class Id {
            public static final String NAME = "id";
            public static final String TYPE = "INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT";
        }

        /**
         * This class defines the IP address column.
         */
        public static final class IPAddress {
            // 16 chars, 15 colons:
            public static final int IPV6_ADDRESS_STRING_LENGTH = 16 + 15;
            public static final String NAME = "ip_address";
            public static final String TYPE = 
                    "VARCHAR(" + IPV6_ADDRESS_STRING_LENGTH + ") NOT NULL";
        }

        /**
         * This class defines the host name column.
         */
        public static final class HostName {
            public static final int MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 253;
            public static final String NAME = "host_name";
            public static final String TYPE =
                    "VARCHAR(" + MAXIMUM_LENGTH + ")"; 
        }

        /**
         * This class defines the port number column.
         */
        public static final class PortNumber {
            public static final String NAME = "port";
            public static final String TYPE = "INT NOT NULL";
        }

        public static final class UserName {
            public static final String NAME = "user_name";
            public static final String TYPE = "VARCHAR(256)";
        }

        /**
         * This class defines the view timestamp.
         */
        public static final class ViewTimestamp {
            public static final String NAME = "viewed_at";
            public static final String TYPE = "TIMESTAMP NOT NULL";
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.sql.SQLStatements.java`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.weblog.viewcounter.sql;

/**
 * This class defines all the SQL statements in the application.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Aug 22, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Aug 22, 2021)
 */
public final class SQLStatements {

    /**
     * The statements for the main table.
     */
    public static final class ViewTable {

        /**
         * The create table statements.
         */
        public static final class Create {

            /**
             * Creates a table for storing the views unless there is one already
             * in the database.
             */
            public static final String CREATE_MAIN_TABLE = 
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + 
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.NAME + 
                    " (\n" +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.Id.NAME + " " +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.Id.TYPE + ",\n" +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.IPAddress.NAME + " " + 
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.IPAddress.TYPE + ",\n" +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.HostName.NAME + " " +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.HostName.TYPE + ",\n" +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.PortNumber.NAME + " " +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.PortNumber.TYPE + ",\n" +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.UserName.NAME + " " + 
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.UserName.TYPE + ",\n" +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.ViewTimestamp.NAME + " " + 
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.ViewTimestamp.TYPE + ",\n" +
                    "PRIMARY KEY (" + SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.Id.NAME + ")) " +
                    "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE " + 
                    "utf8_unicode_ci;;";

        }

        /**
         * The insert data statements. 
         */
        public static final class Insert {

            /**
             * Inserts a new view into the database.
             */
            public static final String INSERT_VIEW = 
                    "INSERT INTO `" + SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.NAME + "` (" +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.IPAddress.NAME + ", " +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.HostName.NAME + ", " +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.PortNumber.NAME + ", " +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.ViewTimestamp.NAME + ") " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
        }

        /**
         * The select data statements.
         */
        public static final class Select {

            /**
             * Returns the total number of views. 
             */
            public static final String GET_NUMBER_OF_VIEWS = 
                    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `" + SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.NAME +
                    "`;";

            /**
             * Returns the most recent view time.
             */
            public static final String GET_MOST_RECENT_VIEW_TIME = 
                    "SELECT MAX(" + 
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.ViewTimestamp.NAME + ") FROM " +
                    SQLDefinitions.ViewTable.NAME + ";";
        }
    }
}
```

At the frontend side, I had to do something like this:

**`viewCounter.js`**

```
function processViewCounter() {
    let span = document.getElementById("view_count_span");
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            renderResults(this.responseText, span);
        }   
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "https://weblog-view-counter.herokuapp.com/countView");
    xhttp.send();
}

function getDateString(dateString) {
    const event = new Date(dateString);
    const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric'};
    return event.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
}

function renderResults(jsonText, textElement) {
    const responseObject = JSON.parse(jsonText);

    if (responseObject["succeeded"]) {
        const numberOfViews = responseObject["numberOfViews"];

        if (numberOfViews) {            
            textElement.innerHTML = "Total views: " + numberOfViews + ".";
        } else {
            textElement.innerHTML = "Total views: N/A.";
        }

        let mostRecentViewTime;

        if (responseObject["mostRecentViewTime"]) {
            mostRecentViewTime = responseObject["mostRecentViewTime"].replace("[Europe/Helsinki]", "");
            mostRecentViewTime = getDateString(mostRecentViewTime);
        } else {
            mostRecentViewTime = "N/A";
        }

        textElement.innerHTML += " Last visit time: " + mostRecentViewTime + ".";
    } else {
        textElement.innerHTML = "Total views: N/A. Last visit time: N/A.";
    }
}
```

### Critique request

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are no beginner, just the terse style I'd also use in my team:

- Singleton anti-pattern in the DAO. Isn't there a DI container around somewhere?
- Too verbose with different exception types. The handling is exactly the same apart from different messages, therefore one exception with a message should be enough. (Always be alert if your error handling is longer than the actual code.)
- `final` classes. Why? How can you tell today that there *never* will be a reason to extend the class? (Hint: you can't) Bad idea™.